# spark-submit: Can I tell spark not to re-upload jars every time

Tags: apache-spark

When calling spark-submit like this `spark-submit -jars my/lib/jars/*.jar my-main-jar.jar`, is it possible to tell spark-submit to not re-upload the jars file if they have been uploaded already?

I have around 100 library jars that are not changing, but I have to wait 10 minutes for `spark-submit` to re-upload them everytime I submit my job.  I have a 30second job I am running to debug an issue that only appears on the cluster but I have to wait 10 minutes for it to re-upload the library jars every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload the jars to the cluster manually and tell Spark to fetch the jars from there. For example, put all the jars into HDFS, then use `hdfs://` url when referencing to them.

Check [Spark's advanced dependency management guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Dikei, you can put them on the cluster, where your spark is running:

If yarn:
Put them manually on HDFS because spark copy them to HDFS before executing the application and also check if it's already there on HDFS or not, if exist then it will skip that jar.

If spark standalone cluster:
This case is even more time consuming because the jar will be copied to each node every time you run your spark hence in such case it's recommended to use any distributed file system to put your data.
(This case is only if you have more than 1 node)

Answer (score 0):

Manually adding the whole list of your jars from HDFS might be a hard task if you have a lot of jars. So, what I do usually, is to upload jars into a HDFS directory (say /tmp/lib/ for example), and this is how I put the list of jars into a variable:

```
JARS=`hdfs dfs -ls -C hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/tmp/lib/*.jar 2>&1 | xargs echo -n | tr '[:space:]' ','`
```

When you call the hdfs "ls", do it with "-C" to print only the file paths, point your hdfs directory with a "hdfs://server:port" prefix to get the hdfs part on the file path. xargs just to avoid the last space, and "tr" to replace spaces with a comma.

JARS now contains a the comma separated list with a full HDFS path to each one of your jars. You can add it as the argument of the --jars option on the spark-submit.

Be careful for access rights management to your jars.